# Dog scratching another

Tags: behavior, health, safety, grooming, scratching

I have 2 dogs and one has a tendency to scratch and then lick the other's back. Sometimes it will happen so much a cut appears and a scab afterward. Is this dangerous and how do I stop this behavior?